# How to read part of a file and save it?

Tags: java, file, csv, reader

I want to know how to read text within a file, containing in the first line for example, Column1, Column2, Column3 etc, Given that I have that line, I want to read up to Column1 and stop and store it in a variable, and if i wanted column2 I just want to read until I find column2 and once I do, I store just "column2" in a variable, etc if that makes any sense.

Basically I want to search and read certain words within a file and store it into a variable to use in other operations going forward. Is that possible? I considered using buffer reader, but i'm not very experienced with java, so any suggestions or code snippets I can review I would appreciate it greatly, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a CSV file. Use a CSV library.

Comment: For a CSV file, use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: No, it's not a csv file, just a text file. It's part of a project and I don't think we are allowed to add any extra libraries. I just want to read parts of the lines and save it in a variable, also keep in mind between column1 and column2 is a separator which i have as a comma if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A real brute force way of doing that would be to just save and load an entire data structure to and from a file. Then you could pick and choose what you want to look at in somewhat of a more comfortable way. The following example saves and loads an integer array called data from a file in the current directory:

```
//Load the data integer array from a file in the current directory
public void loadData(){
    try{
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        data = (int[])ois.readObject();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

//Save the data integer array to a file in the current directory
public void saveData(){
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        oout.writeObject(data);
        oout.close();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```